# PHP/MYSQL Multiple Search Form not showing records with large database content

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search

My search form works when I'm querying in a database with around 10 records only, but when I go more than that, it doesn't show any records and goes to my else "0 records" Please help, below is my php code.

```
    <?php

    $sfname = $_POST["fname"];
    $sgen = $_POST["gen"];
    $sdoc = $_POST["doc"];
    $smisc = $_POST["misc"];
    $ssick = $_POST["sick"];
    $sothers = $_POST["others"];
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    $dbname = "xxx";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if(!empty($sfname) || !empty($sgen) || !empty($sdoc) || !empty($smisc) || !empty($ssick) || !empty($sothers) ){

            $genQueryPart = !empty($sgen) ? "Gender LIKE '%$sgen%'" : "";
            $fnameQueryPart = !empty($sfname) ? "FullName LIKE '%$sfname%'" : "";
            $docQueryPart = !empty($sdoc) ? "Doctor LIKE '%$sdoc%'" : "";
            $miscQueryPart = !empty($smisc) ? "Misc LIKE '%$smisc%'" : "";
           $sickQueryPart = !empty($ssick) ? "Sickness LIKE '%$ssick%'" : "";
            $othersQueryPart = !empty($sothers) ? "Others LIKE '%$sothers%'" : "";

            $arr = array($genQueryPart, $fnameQueryPart,$docQueryPart,$miscQueryPart,$sickQueryPart,$othersQueryPart);

            $sql = "select * from index where";

            $needsAnd = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            if ($arr[$i] != "") {
                if ($needsAnd) {
                    $sql .= " AND ";
                }

                $needsAnd = true;
                $sql .= " " . $arr[$i];
            }

        }

    //Get query on the database
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    //Check results
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
        //Headers
          echo "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>";
            echo "<tr>";
             echo "<th>File ID</th>";
            echo "<th>Full Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Gender</th>";
            echo "<th>Doctor</th>";
            echo "<th>Misc</th>";
            echo "<th>Sickness</th>";
            echo "<th>Others</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

      //output data of each row
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                    echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['FileID']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['FullName']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['Gender']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['Doctor']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['Misc']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['Sickness']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Others']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

            }
                  echo "</table>";
        }
     else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

    } else {
        echo "You must enter at least one value";
    }
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: First, are you sure that there are lot of records returned? Have you checked this? var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($result)) Do this after following  line :  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, it shows " NULL 0 results "

Comment: Add some [error checking](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and/or check the error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be issue with your `empty()` function (depends on your data), use `isset()` instead.

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) : will return true if the variable is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, “0?, 0, and an unset variable.

[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) : will return true only when the variable is not null.

**EDIT**

User got answer from my comments below

*Try debug like this: print $sql before the mysqli_query, copy sql in phpmyadmin and check the query result and query itself.*

Comment: Try debug like this: print $sql before the mysqli_query, copy sql in phpmyadmin and check the query result and query itself.

Comment: Hi Thank you, I've tried lots of different codes already and yes the problem was just the "index" table name, I've tried running the query on the phpmyadmin and to my surprise it does not work, but when i try on a different tablename with the same big number of records it shows something

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried buffering the results?

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
mysqli_store_result($conn);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 ...
}
```

from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php):

> The behaviour of `mysqli_num_rows()` depends on whether buffered or unbuffered result sets are being used. For unbuffered result sets, `mysqli_num_rows()` will not return the correct number of rows until all the rows in the result have been retrieved.

Comment: Unfortunately adding the mysqli_store_result still showed "0 results"